# WinJS: is there any way to pass parameters to x-ms-webview?

Tags: webview, winjs

I'm developing a Windows Store App, and need to pass parameters to a x-ms-webview control in one page. The code (won't work, just for illustration) should look like:

In the webview host page:

```
element.querySelector('#webview').myArray= [1, 2, 3];
```

And in the web view content page:

```
var arr = window.external.mayArray;
```

I've tried to embed the parameters in 'src', or use webview.InvokeScriptAsync(). They seem work. But I guess if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the parameters to be available as the page is being loaded, the passing the values as a query string is the simplest option.

Otherwise:

1. Use `invokeScriptAsync` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn301841)) to call a function within the target document after the load has completed. While it delays the set longer than the query string, it's efficient and allows you to keep executing code and adjusting behavior long after the page has loaded. If you can't use the query string for some reason, I'd suggest this.
2. If the web application has a way to preload the values you need and store them in a Session, it may work, but requires more planning and careful timing.